# Problems with replying to Mailchimp Campaigns at forwarding addresses

Tags: mailchimp, dkim

I have used MailChimp for a few years without any problems.

I set the campaigns up with different reply to email addresses and all was well. But one provider I know was blocking and bouncing emails if the domain I was using was theirs, obviously to stop the spoofing. And as I was getting the warnings to say that google and yahoo would do similar things.

I switched to using forwarding email address from the website so `name@example.com` and then they forwarded into the relevant email addresses at third party providers. As far as I know, it was working. Certainly the forwarders were.

Then I changed hosting and I noticed I wasn't receiving any replies to an email I sent out, checked the log and there were replies.

I have done the DKIM and SPF authentication with MailChimp but still they are not coming through. The tracking log is showing any errors so what am I missing?

The campaigns themselves are getting through, it is just the replying to them that isn't working.

Comment: You need to set the email header with a reply-to: address, this can differ from the send address.

Comment: You can't with Mailchimp you can only put in a "from email address"

Comment: What logs are you checking that shows replies?

Comment: The cPanel "Track Delivery" I also set up an email for testing and the reply went into the email account for although there was a forwarder in place as well it still didn't forward. Something in the headers is still stopping the emails.